# Batch Script to manipulate an existing textfile

Tags: shell, batch-file

I am totally new on writing batch script,busy with the tutorials with the example below I can learn a thing or two.I really need help to write a batch script to insert a line of text at the middle of existing text file.

For example given the file myfile.txt with the contents:

```
a
bcd
efg
hjiklmnop
q
rs
t
uvwxyz
```

The the command  `./put-in-middle.sh  "=== === ===" myfile.txt`
should modify the file to:

```
a
bcd
efg
hjiklmnop
=== === ===
q
rs
t
uvwxyz
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off

rem Count the number of lines in the file with FIND
for /F %%a in ('find /C /V "" ^< %2') do set numLines=%%a

rem Get the number of middle line
set /A middle=numLines/2

rem Process all lines, use FINDSTR /N to insert line numbers
for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /N "^" %2') do (
   rem Echo the original line
   echo/%%b
   rem If the line is the middle one...
   if %%a equ %middle% (
      rem Insert the new line
      echo %~1
   )
)
```

Create previous Batch file as `put-in-middle.bat` and execute it this way:

```
put-in-middle "=== === ===" myfile.txt
```

Notes:

- Previous program does not check for errors, like missing parameters. This checking may be added, if you wish.
- The slash in the command `echo/%%b` is inserted to avoid the message "ECHO is on" if the line is empty. If the line may contain the string "/?", then the command should be changed to `echo(%%b` to avoid that the echo help be displayed in this case (the left parentheses is the only character that do that).
- If the file contains Batch special characters, like `< > | & )`, the `echo/%%b` command fail. In this case, a special processing of files lines must be added. The same point apply to the new inserted line.
- Previous program just display in the screen the new file. If you want to replace the original file, the output must be redirected to an auxiliary file and replace the original one at end:

.

```
(for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /N "^" %2') do (
   . . .
)) > auxiliar.txt
move /Y auxiliar.txt %2
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed` and assuming even number of lines:

```
sed $(( $(wc input -l | cut -d' ' -f1) / 2))'a=== === ===' input
```

And this is the script version `put-in-middle.sh`:

```
line=$1
file=$2
sed $(( $(wc $file -l | cut -d' ' -f1) / 2))"a$line" $file
```